# Example of a school website (college and highschool) which is functional and accessible

Tags: design-patterns, web, analysis

I'm looking for good example of school websites that I can get some inspiration it could be Highschool or College.

I'm planning to build a template or platform of a school website; And I want to provide a good solution for a school which don't have website yet. I want to get some Ideas how school website pages being structured and what are some useful function of a school website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://www.google.com/options/universities.html) is a list of a no. of colleges you can look at and go to their respective website for design and functionality inspiration